# Obfuscating Javascript codes, removing any alpha numeric char from code

Tags: javascript

Using the javascript compatible with ECMAScript for any browser, a logic that be able to obfuscating javascript source removing alphanumeric chars and using only `[]{}!+-*><` to write a any browser functional code.

Presenting some begin steps, then I stop because my logic is chrome only, so need help for a any browser solution.

Doing some tests you will get the further results:

```
[]+[] // ""
{}+[] // 0
{}+{} // NaN
[]+{} // "[object Object]"
![] // false
!![] // true
```

So it's possible to write a string even if you don't type any alpha numeric in your code, like:

```
([]+{})[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]
```

To go a lite far, you even can execute functions doing things like that:

```
[]['sort'] // function sort() { [native code] }
```

Or, to obfuscate it:

```
[][(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+{})[+![]]] // function sort() { [native code] }
```

Now I don't know how to continue for any browser, just for chrome.

I want to get any character, how can I do and be compatible?

How far can I go doing this obfuscating method, I know that the code will not be fast or short, but is very fun way to hide in the source code things.

What is the **best logic** to go further and be able to write any string or source code.

**EDIT:**

I don't wan't a obfuscation generator, I want the logic to do that, has many ways, but, some of then just work in one or other browsers, must be an way to work in all browsers without leaving the ECMAScript specifications.

Comment: Use this link and close your question: http://discogscounter.getfreehosting.co.uk/js-noalnum_com.php

Comment: @AndyRay no... I don't find my answer in link that you send, their code don't work and I still stocked in this step, will be very sad to close question before an real answer. Don't you have an tutorial or something better then just an tool for obfuscating that doesn't works?

Comment: I know this is old, but: http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html